# What can be the causes of the ChangeConflictException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

My Code is simple:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
    var image = ctx.Images.Single(i => i.ImageID == 3122);
    ctx.Images.DeleteOnSubmit(image);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I always get `Row not found or changed.`

I have read in other posts if I set `Update Check` to `Never` it will fix it, and it does.  But I am more interested in why it is happening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the row you are updating is being updated by some other process (maybe a trigger) in between the time you read the row into memory and the time you attempt to write it back to the database.